# Customizing methods signature in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

There is a simple way to format the methods signature in sphinx?
I am using RTD Theme, and building to html.

The problems I have at the moment are:

- custom types annotations created using typing module are being printed in their full form, but I would like just their name to be printed (ex. `CustomType = Union[type1, type2, type3]`should be rendered as simply `CustomType`, but gets rendered as `Union[type1, type2, type3]` instead)
- method signature is printed on a single line, I would like it to be printed as an indented custom form
- method signature should highlight syntax somehow like in an IDE

I am not sure how to achieve these customisations, to me it seems there isn't any option in the html theme conf to do so.

The first thing I tried was something like [this code](https://gitext.gfz-potsdam.de/sec55-public/xarray-topo/blob/master/doc/conf.py), but I kinda got stucked.

In a first moment I also thought about doing a fork of sphinx (like this user did to try to solve another annoying problem [[PR]](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/1882/files/0c1136c9c617f18c83535ee05cba3019440d2e47#diff-84bfd2ad46b7c8e97e5a06abb886c065R175)), but then I realized that something like this is really complex if you don't know the project very well...

I will provide further details if necessary.

Comment: @mzjn why did you removed the #sphinx tag?

Comment: Because that tag is incorrect. You are not asking about the Sphinx search engine (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphinx).

Comment: ok great, thank you then :)

Comment: Regarding the second bullet, see https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1514

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fully satisfies what I was looking for, but at least from the release `2.1` they added the possibility to exclude type hints from the method signature.

You can enable this feature by setting in the docs `conf.py` file, the following line:

```
autodoc_typehints = "none"
```

I would also suggest to then set this variable to specify a minimal Sphinx version:

```
needs_sphinx = "2.1"
```